# Lubuntu 14.04 Dual Mon with ARandR Screen Layout Editor

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, xrandr, pcmanfm

I have make use of the XRandR with Lubuntu 14.04 on my old VAIO TZ17GN notebook. It working  fine for my dual monitors situation. But I found some tricky issues.

### Desktop issue

First of all, I can't right click to popup a context menu on my main monitor. The menu only work on the secondary monitor.

After I have configure OpenBox Manager to show Home/RecycleBin/RemovableStorageDevice icons on the desktop, the menu (Desktop right click context menu) has been changed to another one that mass with many incorrect shortcut items. If I click on those item, the current user desktop session must crashed and return to the login screen.

### File Manager

The second issue is while I want to create/place files or folders on desktop by copying them by terminal command or file manager, those files/folders won't appears. At the same time, I found that the default file manager (PCmanfc) won't show up any more too. If a file manager has already opened before something moved into the Desktop Folder, the file manager must be freeze instantly.

Is it a bug? Or I should not use the ARandR to belong with Lubuntu 14.04?

Thanks a lot.